# running a php page via crontab and having issues with if file_exists

Tags: php, cron, file-exists

I have a question...I am running a php page daily through a crobtab and I seem to be getting erros when this code is run..

```
include(CLASS_PATH .'EmailAddressValidator.php');
```

so I applied this code...

```
if(file_exists('/var/www/testsite/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php')){
    include('/var/www/testsite/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php');
}else{
    include(CLASS_PATH .'EmailAddressValidator.php');
}
```

but I also have live site at

`/var/www/livesite/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php`

and its been a pain doing back and forth changing my code from`testsite` to `livesite` is there an easier way to do this..

I've tried..

```
if(file_exists('/var/www/testsite/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php')){
    include('/var/www/testsite/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php');
elseif(file_exists('/var/www/livesite/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php')){
    include('/var/www/livesite/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php');
}else{
    include(CLASS_PATH .'EmailAddressValidator.php');
}
```

Testing out all answers...will have a vote by monday end day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relative paths instead

```
../classes/EmailAddressValidator.php
```

or whatever the path is.

Comment: okay why?, it works for me... do you mean it may should be `./classes/EmailAddressValidator.php` or something else? I do not now in which file you includes from.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you're using **consistently defined directory locations**, especially if you're frequently changing between production and development environments.  If you also work on different operating systems, getting the directory structures right can be a real pain in the neck, so if you centralise things it makes your life a lot easier.

For example, are you sure you're defining `CLASS_PATH` as a constant?

I'd suggest finding the location of the current directory before you do anything else:

```
$current_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
```

and then using this variable to go onwards and upwards:

```
$test_dir = $current_dir . '../testsite/';
$live_dir = $current_dir . '../livesite/';
$class_dir = $current_dir . '../classes/';

if(file_exists("$test_dir/EmailAddressValidator.php"))
{
    include("$test_dir/EmailAddressValidator.php");
}
elseif(file_exists("$live_dir/EmailAddressValidator.php"))
{
    include("$live_dir/EmailAddressValidator.php");
}
else
{
    include("$class_dir/EmailAddressValidator.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) you could use a configuration file or environment variable to setup your "environment":

environment.ini

```
environment = livesite
```

cronscript.php:

```
$config      = parse_ini_file("./environment.ini");
$environment = $config["environment"];

include "/var/www/$environment/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php";
```

Now add the environment.ini to your livesite and testsite, each with it's corresponding entry in the configuration file.

Of course you can use other configuration types, such as constants (`define("MY_ENVIRONMENT", "livesite")`.

2.) Another approach would be to use relative file paths:

```
include "../relative/path/to/classes/EmailAddressValidator.php"
```

3.) Use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` variable to manipulate the if else in runtime.

I mean you could get whether you are using `testsite` or `livesite` by doing some `substr` or `explode` on the variable and pass that with the path in the `if else` statements

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do the following

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'EmailAddressValidator.php';
```

This would automatically find the path of the currently running file and include the file you want based on its position in relation to the running file.

Using the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant will ensure your code will work on either windows or linux systems